# I want add a class and remove a class based on div's id

Tags: jquery

I want add a class and remove a class  based on div's id
  basically .PMessages_toolbar_collapseAll class and .PMessages_toolbar_expandAll class should be         removed when user click's it and add semi-active"

```
<div class="coll-Expa-wrapper"> 
<div class="PMessages_toolbar_collapseAll " id="collapseAllPrivateMessage">
    Collapse all 
</div>//<------when user clicks  it  class .PMessages_toolbar_collapseAll should be removed and          .semi-active class should be added

<div class="semi-active" id="expandAllPrivateMessage"
    Expand all
</div>>//<------when user clicks  it .semi-active class should be removed and         .PMessages_toolbar_expandAll class should be added



  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.semi-active').bind('click',classtoggle)
   });

function classtoggle()
{
 var toggler=$('.semi-active').attr('id');

 if(toggler =="expandAllPrivateMessage" )
    {    

 $(this).removeClass('semi-active').addClass('PMessages_toolbar_expandAll');
 $('.PMessages_toolbar_collapseAll').removeClass('PMessages_toolbar_collapseAll').addClass('semi-      activ');
   }

else if(toggler =="collapseAllPrivateMessage" )
    {
        $(this).removeClass('semi-active').addClass('PMessages_toolbar_collapseAll');
         $('.PMessages_toolbar_expandAll').removeClass('PMessages_toolbar_expandAll').addClass('semi-active');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $divs = $('.PMessages_toolbar_collapseAll, .semi-active').on('click', function(){
        $divs.toggleClass('PMessages_toolbar_collapseAll semi-active')
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JeBXF/)

Comment: thanks arun but I need flowing function
 <div class="PMessages_toolbar_collapseAll " id="collapseAllPrivateMessage">
    Collapse all 
</div><----this div's  toggle classes are .PMessages_toolbar_collapseAll  and .semi-active

<div class="semi-active" id="expandAllPrivateMessage"
    Expand all
</div>><----this div's  toggle classes are .semi-active and .PMessages_toolbar_ExpandAll

toggle function should be trigger when user clicks either of divs